# Retrieve results from regexp_matches as one row

Tags: regex, postgresql

So, if have this string `aassdd`

This code:

`regexp_matches('aassdd', 'a', 'g')`

returns 2 different rows.

It is possible to retrieve all matches as one row? for example as `array` type as one row, that is from code above, needed result is: `{a,a}`

Comment: But, if remove `'g'`, we obtain just first match, and not all matches as one row, right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fact that regexp_matches() returns a set rather than a scalar is understandable but still somewhat annoying.

The only workaround I found is this somewhat ugly query:

```
select array_agg(i)
from (
   select (regexp_matches('aassdd', 'a', 'g'))[1] i 
)  t
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what is an alternative solution for `regexp_matches`? I'm using redshift database, so I can only use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, `REGEXP_COUNT`, and `REGEXP_INSTR` function.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT ARRAY(select array_to_string(regexp_matches('aassdd', 'a', 'g'),''));
```

Comment: This is a tolerable way to return multiple occurrences of a regular expression match as an array.  Oracle programmers could translate `regexp_substr(string, pattern, 1, 7)` into the delightful `select (array(select array_to_string(regexp_matches(string, pattern, 'g'),'')))[7]` to retrieve the 7th match.

Answer (score 2):

If regexp_matches() takes as parameter a column of an indexed table, there is one more way:

```
SELECT rid, array_agg(number) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
       rid, 
       (regexp_matches(column,'[0-9]+','g'))[1] as number 
    FROM table) t
GROUP BY rid
```

Answer (score 0):

## With [`plperl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html)

If you're looking for something somewhat performant,

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperl;

CREATE FUNCTION regexp_return_matches(text, text)
RETURNS text[]
AS $$
  my ( $input, $pattern ) = @_;
  $pattern = quotemeta($pattern);
  return [$input =~ m/($pattern)/g];
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;

SELECT regexp_return_matches('aassdd', 'a');
 regexp_return_matches 
-----------------------
 {a,a}
(1 row)
```